# Evaluate $\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}\log\left[ \frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12+\frac{k}{2}\right)} \right]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am struggling to evaluate the following series:

> $$\mathcal{S}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}\log\left[ \frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12+\frac{k}{2}\right)} \right]=-0.13360...$$

From what I tried, I figured out that, if a closed form does exist, it must be really difficult to find.

Here are my attempts:

**Attempt (1):**

using the fact that, for $\Re(z)>0$ and $\Re(z-x)>0$
$$\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1-x)}=e^{-\gamma x}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left[ \left(1-\frac{x}{z+n}\right)e^{\frac{x}{n}} \right]$$
$$\implies \frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{\Gamma\left(z+\frac12\right)}=e^{-\frac{\gamma}{2}}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left[ \left(1-\frac{1}{2(z+n)}\right)e^{\frac{1}{2n}} \right]$$
$$\implies \frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12+\frac{k}{2}\right)}=e^{-\frac{\gamma}{2}}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left[ \left(1-\frac{1}{k+2n}\right)e^{\frac{1}{2n}} \right]$$
$$\implies \log\left[ \frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12+\frac{k}{2}\right)} \right]=-\frac{\gamma}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{2n}+\log\left(1-\frac{1}{k+2n}\right)\right]$$
and here the tough part is the double sum that we end up with after plugging this value into the original $\mathcal{S}$. Notice that all these steps where valid only for $k>1$, so we would get
$$\mathcal{S}=\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)+\frac{\gamma}{2}\left(1-\frac{\pi^2}{12} \right) +\sum_{k=2}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}\left[\frac{1}{2n}+\log\left(1-\frac{1}{k+2n}\right)\right]$$
which had me stuck.

**Attempt (2):**

I tried splitting the sum into even and odd terms, in order to get rid of the gamma functions. For instance, the odd terms form the following series:
$$\mathcal{S_1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}\log\left[ \frac{\Gamma(k+1+\frac12)}{\Gamma(k+1)} \right]$$
Now, using the fact that
$$\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac12)}{\Gamma (n)}={{2n} \choose n}\frac{n}{4^n}\sqrt{\pi}$$
we have
$$\mathcal{S_1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}\log\left[{{2k} \choose k}\frac{2k+1}{4^k}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \right]$$
$$=\frac{\pi^2}{8}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}\log\left[{{2k} \choose k}\frac{2k+1}{4^k} \right]$$
but now this series has this $\log$ term that is difficult to handle. We can't even split it using $\log$ properties, since the resulting series wouldn't converge at all.

**Attempt (3):**

It can be shown that
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x^a)}{1+x}\text{d}x \text{d}a=2\log^22+\frac{\pi^2}{24}\log\pi+\mathcal{S}$$
and notice that here, changing the order of integration is allowed. I couldn't evaluate this double integral either in the end.

**EDIT:**

**Attempt (4):**

Using [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1878382p12770310) we can rewrite $\mathcal{S}$ as:
$$\mathcal{S}=-\frac{\pi^2}{24}\log\pi-\int_0^1\frac{\text{Li}_2(-x)+\frac{\pi^2}{12}}{(x+1)\log x}\text{d}x$$
and this integral is similar to the ones that appear [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493078/how-to-evaluate-int-01-frac-frac-pi26-operatornameli-21-x1-x?noredirect=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3832177/how-to-evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-frac-left-1-rightnh-2nn2-exclu?noredirect=1), so maybe it can be expressed as a series involving harmonic numbers as well?

Comment: The use of square brackets for grouping expressions is becoming obsolete and now is mostly used only in very elementary Mathematics. You should try to use only $($ and $)$, and leave $[$ to $]$ for other uses.

Comment: Not really a closed form, but I found $$
\mathcal{S} =  - \frac{{\zeta '(2)}}{4} - \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{{12}}\log 2 - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\tanh \left( {\frac{t}{2}} \right)\frac{{{\mathop{\rm Li}\nolimits} _2 ( - {\rm e}^{ - t} )}}{t}{\rm d}t} .
$$

Comment: The last formulation is really interesting .

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici using the last formulation, together with Gary's result, I arrived at the following integral:
$$\int_0^1\frac {\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\text{Li}_2(-x)+\frac{\pi^2}{6}} {(x+1)\log x}\text{d}x=\pi^2\left( \frac{\log2}{4}+\frac{\gamma}{12}-\log A \right)$$
which I think it's beautiful, but useless in this context unfortunately.

Comment: (3) would be extremely hard since even some fixed values of $a$, the closed form expression is really horrid to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426325

Comment: @oO_ƲRF_Oo yea I lost all my hope on this one too long ago

Answer (score 3):

If you would accept to stay with an infinite summation, you could use
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}\log\left[ \frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12+\frac{k}{2}\right)} \right]$$ $$S=\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\right)+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}\log\left[ \frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12+\frac{k}{2}\right)} \right]$$ Now, using Stirling approximation
$$\log\left[ \frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12+\frac{k}{2}\right)} \right]=\frac{1}{2} (\log (k)-\log (2))+\frac 14 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n} {b_n} \,k^{-(2n+1)}$$ where the $a_n$ and $b_n$ form respectively sequences $A275994$ and $A219931$ in $OEIS$.

This would make
$$S=\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi ^2-6}{12}  \log (2)-\frac{1}{4} \zeta '(2)+$$ $$\frac 14 \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac {a_n} {b_n} \,k^{-(2n+3)}$$ and
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\,k^{-(2n+3)}=\left(1-2^{-2 (n+1)}\right) \zeta (2 n+3)-1$$

Comment: Note that this is formal, since the expansion for the gamma functions is a divergent asymptotic series. Claude missed the $k$-sum in the line before the last.

Comment: @Gary. Thanks for pointing. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Zima. Sorry for the missing $\sum$

Comment: @Gary so the last series Claude gave is not convergent? Is this what you mean by formal?

Comment: @Zima Yes that is what I mean. Writing $=$ for the expansion for the $\log$ of the gamma ratio is incorrect. It should be $\sim$. It is a divergent asymptotic series useful for large $k$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion

Comment: @Gary understood, thank you